# Nginx redirection and serve from subfolder if 403

Tags: nginx, server, web-config, webserver

I have my site directory as follows,

```
Sites
    - site 1
        index.html
    - site 2
        - docs
            index.html
```

I like to set up the nginx server in such a way that if the location is `/site1` it should server `index.html` and if the location is `site2` it should try if there is any `index.html` if not serve from `docs/index.html`. I tried to get this in different ways one of which is as,

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name courses.myserver.com;
    location /site1 {
        root /Sites/site 1;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /site2 {
        root /Sites/site2;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/docs/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

But it is not doing what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file is formed by concatenating the value of `root` to the value of the URI. Your URI already contains "site1", so the value of `root` should not. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Looking at your directory structure, you can probably use the same value of `root` for all your locations, in which case you should place it in the `server` block, and allow each `location` to inherit the same value.

For example:

```
root /Sites;
index index.html index.htm;

location /site1 {
}
location /site2 {
    ...
}
```

---

The `index` directive is invoked for URIs ending with a `/`. If you want `index.html` and `docs/index.html` to be tested for URIs ending with a `/`, you can add the special case to the `index` directive.

For example:

```
location /site2 {
    index index.html index.htm docs/index.html;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want `docs/index.html` to be taken as a default for any URI that doesn't otherwise match a file or index, add the default URI to the end of the `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location /site2 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/docs/index.html;
}
```